# Current URL in href

Tags: java, playframework

I want to add the current URL(returnTo - string type) in this part of code :`href="@routes.AuthenticationController.login(**returnTo**)"`. I want to use it to redirect to the requested URL after login. Right now if a user is not logged in, gets a message on the page with Unauthorized  403, and has to use the log in button that will redirect them to the login page.
For example if I am on http://localhost:9000/getByProductId/43, after the login I want to get to this page.

The login function looks like this:

```
public static Result login(String returnTo) {
    return ok(views.html.forms.loginForm.render(form(Login.class), returnTo));
}
```

The page with restricted message looks like this

```
<div class="hero-unit center">
        <h1>Access Restricted <small><font face="Tahoma" color="red">Unauthorized  403</font></small></h1>
        <br />
        @if(User.findCurrentUser() == null || User.findCurrentUser().getIdentifier() == null) {
            <p>You have to login first to access this functionality.</p>
            <p>
            <a href="@routes.AuthenticationController.login(**returnTo**)" class="btn btn-large btn-info" ><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i> Log in</a>
        }
```

Comment: Which play version is the application using? Is it doing a redirect to render that page?

Answer (score 1):

You can get current URL from RequestHeader object

```
public static Result login() {
    String uri = request().uri();
    return ok(views.html.forms.loginForm.render(form(Login.class), uri));
}
```

Documentation about RequestHeader:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/java/play/mvc/Http.RequestHeader.html